# ¿Cómo obtener la hora del servidor con JS Y PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy creando un sitio donde obtenga la hora del servidor en php y después pasarla a una variable de JS, esto para realizar algunas otras acciones.

Este es mi ejemplo de lo que tengo:

Archivo reloj.php: En este archivo obtengo la hora del servidor

```
<?php 

echo $s = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

?>
```

Archivo index.php: En este archivo obtengo el resultado del echo establecido en el archivo reloj.php.

```
    <?php include("reloj.php"); ?>
    <input type="text" id="serverDate" style="opacity: 20;" >
<script>
    let reloj = document.getElementById("serverDate");
    
    function muestraReloj () {
            fetch("reloj.php")
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => reloj.value = data); 
                console.log(reloj.value);
           var fechaYHora = new Date(reloj.value).toLocaleTimeString();
            console.log(fechaYHora);
    }
    setInterval(muestraReloj, 1000)
</script>
```

Me funciona correctamente todo, pero no quiero mostrar la hora que se imprime en el echo del archivo reloj, en el ejemplo que establezco si quito el echo entonces falla por que no muestra nada. El input con el id serverDate puedo ocultarlo pero el echo del archivo reloj.php no se como se podría ocultar, alguna idea?

Este es el resultado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar tu echo por una función que retorne lo que esta dentro del objeto date():

```
<?php 
obtenerFecha(){
    $s = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    return $s;
}
?>

obtenerFecha();
```

Comment: Gracias por comentar. El obtenerFecha();  si lo pongo afuera de la llave de php me manda error obtengo solo obtenerFecha();